# Laravel Controller method not found for homepage

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I am aware that my code is slightly wrong (hence my post!). I am wanting my 'home' view to be displayed when a visitor accesses the '/' part of the website.

Currently, the view works when a user accesses the '/home' part of the website. I am currently pulling my hair out on how to do this!

Route.php:

```
Route::controller('/', 'HomeController');
Route::controller('users', 'UsersController');
Route::get('events/{id}/{slug}', 'EventsController@show');
Route::controller('events', 'EventsController');
```

HomeController.php:

```
<?php

class HomeController extends BaseController {

    protected $layout = "layouts.main";

    public function getHome(){

        $events = myApp\Event::where('date','>=', DB::raw('CURDATE()'))->first();
        $this->layout->content = View::make('home', array('events' => $events));
    }
}
```

Home.blade.php:

```
<div class="col-md-4">
    <h2>Next Event</h2>
    <h3>{{$events->title}}</h3>
    <p>Presented by {{ $events->consultant()->first()->title }} {{ $events->consultant()->first()->surname }}</p>
    <b><p>{{ date("j F Y", strtotime($events->date)) }} from {{ date("g:ia", strtotime($events->start_time)) }}</p></b>
    <a class="btn btn-success" href="{{ URL::to('events/' . $events->slug) }}">Book your place now.</a>
</div>
```

---

I have managed to get the view working with the '/' directory by using this within my routes.php:

```
Route::get('/', function(){
    return View::make('home');
});
```

However, I am presented with the error:

> Undefined variable: events (View:/Users/Sites/gp/app/views/home.blade.php).

It's as if, the HomeController isn't passing the 'events' array into the view, by just changing the route?! Any help/remedy/explanation would be hugely appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's how Laravel RESTful controllers works, but you can create a new route for `/`, before your other routes, pointing to that action:

```
Route::controller('users', 'UsersController');
Route::get('events/{id}/{slug}', 'EventsController@show');
Route::controller('events', 'EventsController');

Route::get('/', 'HomeController@getHome');
Route::controller('/', 'HomeController');
```

**EDIT**

You have to understand that the Laravel Routing System tries to resolve a route as fast as it can, so if it finds a route that fits the current URI, it will use that route and forget about all the others. An example:

```
Route::get('/{variable}' 'Controller@action');
```

This is pretty generic route and can be resolved to anything, even

```
http://your-site.dev/events
```

So, if you add that route before this one:

```
Route::get('events/{id}/{slug}', 'EventsController@show');
```

Your events route will never be hit. That's why your most generic route have to be the last one.

Comment: That works perfectly, thank you, Antonio. A quick question if I may, why do I need to call the controller after the get method? Would the @getHome function do all the work? I know it doesn't of course! I'm just thinking outside the box.

Comment: Also, in order to get my application to work, I have had to change around my routes to this order - http://pastebin.com/e8zcuUzL, is there a reason why? I appreciate the help, Antonio.

Comment: Routing in Laravel works in the order you define them and your Route::controller() will define a route for `/` too, but it will redirect it to `/home`, so if you first define the same route, the one Route::controller() defined won't work.

Comment: Edited to give you an example that might help better understand routing.